# Storing a value from an array without changing it in Node-RED

Tags: arrays, node.js, node-red

In my current project I am trying to calculate altitude from pressure and temperature measurements. I've managed to send the three types of data gathered from the sensors (temperature, pressure, state of the safety belt [0 or 1]) to a function node, where they can be processed together. Pressure and temperature are composed as two arrays of two elements: ambient[t0, t1], pressure[pr0, pr1]. The data arrives to the function node every 2 seconds.

I want to calculate the actual altitude according to the following logic:

1) When the first **ambient** and **pressure** arrays arrive, I retrieve t0, pr0, calculate the initial altitude which is **hInit** ~ t0/pr0;

2) Afterwards, further altitudes **hChecked** calculated from t1, pr1, t2, pr2 .... tN, prN, will be compared with the initial altitude which will give us actual altitude h.
**h = hChecked - hInitial**;

3) if h < 0 we need to choose another initial altitude, i.e. retrieve and store new t0, pr0;

4) if h > 3 we need to check the state of the belt. if 1 - state is safe; if 0 - lock your belt;

I have the following code:

```
if(ambient !== null && pressure !== null && lockerState != null) {

    var hInit;
    var hChecked;
    var h;

    //p0 is the hardcoded pressure on the level of the sea
    //for the current area
    var p0 = 1019;

    //assing new variables for initital pressure and temp
    var tInit = ambient[0];
    var pInit = pressure[0];

    //variables for the checked pressure and temp
    var tChecked = ambient[1];
    var pChecked = pressure[1];

    //altitude hInit (hInit) is measure when the testbest is turned on

    hInit = (((Math.pow((p0/pInit), (1/5.257)))-1)*(tInit + 273.15))/0.0065;
    //hChecked is the measured altitude afterwards
    hChecked = (((Math.pow((p0/pChecked), (1/5.257)))-1)*(tChecked + 273.15))/0.0065;

    //h is the actual altitude the worker is working on
    h = hChecked - hInit;

    //in the case if a worker turned the testbed on 
    //when he was operating on the altitude he then
    //might go down so altitude can reduce.
    //therefore if the altitude h is < 0 we need to
    //calculate a new reference 

    if (h < 0) {
        var tInit = ambient[0];
        var pInit = pressure[0];
        var tChecked = ambient[1];
        var pChecked = pressure[1];

        hInit = (((Math.pow((p0/pInit), (1/5.257)))-1)*(tInit + 273.15))/0.0065;
        hChecked = (((Math.pow((p0/pChecked), (1/5.257)))-1)*(tChecked + 273.15))/0.0065;
        h = hChecked - hInit;        
    }
    //check current altitude
    while (h>=0) {
        if (h>2) {   
            if (lockerState == 1) {
                msg.payload = "safe";
                return msg;
            } else if (lockerState === 0) {
                msg.payload = "lock your belt!";
                //basically i want to send a 1 signal
                //to the buzzer which is a pin on the RPI3
                //so probably msg.payload = 1;
                return msg;
            }
        }
    }
} else return msg;
```

**My problem** is that I can't store the initial data t0, pr0 form the first **ambient** and **pressure** arrays when the system is is turned on without changing it. Every time the program starts to execute the code it changes t0 and pr0. What I am trying to achieve is to change the initial data when h is less than 0.

Would be grateful if someone could share clues how to solve this

Comment: Have you tried using a database or setting environmental variables?

Comment: @alexi2 To be fair I am new in coding. Could you explain me how it works in few words?

Comment: updated the answer with an example of using fs, very basic but it should get you started.

Comment: No probs happy to help.

Comment: I think you would do better discussing what you are trying to achieve on the Node-RED mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red) as Stack overflow isn't really suited for the back and forth discussion that I think will be required to help guide you.

Comment: Sorry for pointing you in the wrong direction, hope you solve the issue there! Good luck

Comment: @hardillb thank you for advising a specific forum! will ask there as well.

Comment: @alexi2 that's alright. you gave me the idea to solve it. thanks!